# チェックボックスなどでの入力や選択の可能・不可能切り替えの是非

Tags: javascript, html, form

ウェブフォームでチェックボックスを入れることで、入力や選択可能の制御を行う場合があります。
これはUIとして正しいのでしょうか？
そのような制限を設けなくとも、受信したデータからは単純に入力や選択がなければ、該当項目の値はなしと判断できます。
ユーザー側にとって、事前にチェックボックスがあることで、間違いが少なくなるように思いますが、ワンクッション発生することになります。
みなさんどう考えられますか？

コードビューなどを含まない質問なので、不適切でしたら、指摘ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ユーザーにオプトイン意思表明を行わせるという意味で、チェックを付ける手間を**掛けさせる**ためにわざわざやっている場合がありそう、とか思ったりします（具体的サイトとか挙動とか示されていないので単なる憶測です）

Comment: 例題を明瞭に示せていないようで、申し訳ないです。
チェックボックスで必要性を明確にチェックしてもらうことでユーザー側の入力ミスは防げると思います。
その反面、余計なワンクッションになってしまうため、多用するのはどうかという疑問がありました。